# Changing all images on timer with JS

Tags: javascript, image

I have this 3x3 img gallery. I need all of them to change every certain time with JS. 
So far I managed to do this to one of the images. I don't know how to target them all.

```
<script>
var images = ["http://lorempixel.com/250/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/"];
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
if(images.length == i){
i = 0;
}
else {
document.getElementByClassName('galleryItem').src = images[i];
i++;
}
},1000);
</script>

<div class="galleryWrapper">
<div class="galleryItem item1">
<img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture1">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item2">
<img id="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture2">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item3">
<img id="image3" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture3">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item4">
<img id="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture4">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item5">
<img id="image5" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture5">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item6">
<img id="image6" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture6">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item7">
<img id="image7" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture7">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item8">
<img id="image8" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture8">
</div>
<div class="galleryItem item9">
<img id="image9" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture9">
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know JS at all so don't be too harsh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using `document.getElementsByClassName('galleryItem')` and looping over all of them instead of selecting by ID, unless you want to change them to different images.

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup __in__ the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle/jsbin). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I edited the request so now it should be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onload` from your `body` element (Using DOMContentLoaded event instead it is less intrusive).

```
var imageList = ["http://lorempixel.com/250/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/"],
    imageListCounter = 0,
    imageEls;

function swapImages() {
    var i = 0, len = imageEls.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        imageEls[i].src = imageList[imageListCounter];
    }
    imageListCounter++;
    if (imageListCounter > imageList.length - 1) {
        imageListCounter = 0;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    imageEls = document.querySelectorAll('.galleryItem img');
    setInterval(swapImages, 1000);
});
```

What we are doing here is:

- on document ready store all the image elements in imageEls
- then start a timer, calling swapImages every 1 second
- swapImages iterates over images and changes the .src to what is in the next one in imageList
- when the imageListCounter reaches the end of imageList it resets to 0

So the complete html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        var imageList = ["http://lorempixel.com/250/200/", "http://lorempixel.com/250/150/"],
            imageListCounter = 0,
            imageEls;

        function swapImages() {
            var i = 0, len = imageEls.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                imageEls[i].src = imageList[imageListCounter];
            }
            imageListCounter++;
            if (imageListCounter > imageList.length - 1) {
                imageListCounter = 0;
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
            imageEls = document.querySelectorAll('.galleryItem img');
            setInterval(swapImages, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="galleryWrapper">
        <div class="galleryItem item1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture1">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item2">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture2">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item3">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture3">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture4">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item5">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture5">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item6">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture6">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item7">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture7">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item8">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture8">
        </div>
        <div class="galleryItem item9">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/" alt="picture9">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you set the image name to `image1`, you can just change to `'image'+i+''`
`document.getElementById('image'+i+'').src = images[i];`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var e = 1; e < 10; e++) 
{ 
  var ImgID = 'image' + e; 
 document.getElementById(ImgID).src = images[i];
}
```

If you were using jquery you could just do a foreach on all the img elements. but the above will work. if you have 9 images with the ID of image1, image2, image3... you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your else block

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(j=0;j<imgs.length;j++){
    imgs[j].src = images[i];  
}        
i++;
```

instead of this

```
document.getElementByClassName('gallery').src = images[i];
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your images a class attribute with the same value.

assuming you use the value "imagetags", replace your `document.getElementById()` line with the following:

```
var elements = document.GetElementsByClassName("imagetags");
for (var elem in elements){
    elements[elem].src = images[i];
}
```